# Terminal Services Profile Path

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing a powershell script to pull up the roaming profile path of users in our active directory. however I am getting the following error message

```
$ADUser = Get-ADUser nstark | Select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
$ADUser = [ADSI]”LDAP://$ADUser”
$RoamingProfilePath = $ADUser.psbase.InvokeGet(“terminalservicesprofilepath”)
```

> Method invocation failed because
>   [System.Management.Automation.PSInternalMemberSet] does not contain a
>   method named 'InvokeGet'. At line:1 char:1
>   + $ADUser.psbase.InvokeGet(“terminalservicesprofilepath”)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (InvokeGet:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

I am not sure how to fix this issue or why I am getting it to begin with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just get this from Active Directory. Isn't it called `ProfilePath`:

```
Get-ADUser nstark -Properties ProfilePath
```

If you wanted to get it with ADSI, there is no method called `InvokeGet` on `psbase`. You would just call it this way:

```
$ADUser = Get-ADUser nstark | Select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
$ADUser = [ADSI]”LDAP://$ADUser”
$RoamingProfilePath = $ADUser.InvokeGet(“terminalservicesprofilepath”)
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept your answer ProfilePath is indeed what I needed